# Compare two +new Date strings

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to compare two different `+new Date`, but sometimes it gives different results.

So this is how I'm doing it:
The first user sends a request to Firebase(server) and sets value 
`time: +new Date` like this

```
firebase.userRef.set({
   time: +new Date
})
```

Then the second user sends a similar request to Firebase and sets value like above. Then second user finds user 1 in query and checks who sent the request first. Like so:

```
firebase.usersRef.child(user_uid).once("value",function(snapshot){
  firebase.usersRef.child(current_uid).once("value",function(childSnapshot) {
    if(snapshot.val().time > childSnapshot.val().time){
       //current user requested first
    } else {
      //user found requested first
    }
  });
});
```

But, sometimes both users gets the wrong answer. So the users think that current user requested first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way of setting the timestamp would be using [ServerValues](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue):

```
userRef.set({
  time: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
})
```

Using server values would be better since the value is fetched once it hits Firebase's server and would make your comparisons accurate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just have to test and see if the problem comes up again. Because sometimes it works flawless and sometimes it don't, but using serverValues would be make more sense.